# Haskell return Either Double Bool

Tags: haskell, boolean, double, either

I have simple code

```
delta a b c = b*b - (4*a*c)

mz1 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
mz1 a b c = (-b - sqrt(delta a b c)) / (2*a)

mz2 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
mz2 a b c = (-b + sqrt(delta a b c)) / (2*a)

mz0 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
mz0 a b c = (-b) / (2*a)

kwad :: (Enum a) => a -> a -> a -> Either Double Bool
kwad a b c 
    | delta a b c == 0 = Left mz0 a b c
    | delta a b c < 0 = Right False
    | otherwise = Left mz1 a b c
```

I'm just starting to learn Haskell and I have no idea how to return either Bool or Double, could anybody help?

Error is:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `a -> a -> a -> Either Double Bool'
>             with actual type `Either (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double) >b0'
> The function `Left' is applied to four arguments,
> but its type `(Double -> Double -> Double -> Double)
>               -> Either (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double) b0'
> has only one
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `kwad` function has three parameters of type `Enum a => a`. In other words, they can take any `a` as long as it is enumerable. Your `mz` functions expects their values to be of type `Double`. I would suggest changing the type signature of `kwad` so it takes `Double` arguments instead, like so:

```
kwad :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Either Double Bool
```

This guarantees that the values you put into `kwad` are `Double`s, and therefore suitable for your `mz` functions as well!

---

You also need to wrap the argument to `Left` in parentheses, like so:

```
Left (mz0 a b c)
```

This means that you want to put the entire `mz0 a b c` result into a `Left`, and not anything else.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I've tried this, it still gives mi error:     Couldn't match expected type `Double
                                  -> Double -> Double -> Either Double Bool'
                with actual type `Either (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double) b0'
    The function `Left' is applied to four arguments,
    but its type `(Double -> Double -> Double -> Double)
                  -> Either (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double) b0'
    has only one
    In the expression: Left mz0 a b c

Comment: @user1337192 Of course! I'm sorry I missed that. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you that worked! I have another question do you know how to "write" answer like printf in c? I ask because now I have output like "Right False" and also I would like to return values of mz1 and mz2 in case of "otherwise"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, unfortunately. You might want to post it as a separate question on this site, and try to explain what you want in greater detail.

Comment: I've already dealt with it, what I means was: otherwise = printf "MZ1: %f MZ2: %f" (mz1 a b c) (mz2 a b c), one last thing as the result I get "MZ1: -19.74679434480896 MZ2: -0.2532056551910369", do there always have to be quotation mark in result?

Comment: What I suspect is happening with the quotation marks is that printf is returning a formatted String, not directly printing IO.  Then the String is printed as a result in ghci, which adds quotation marks.  It is also _possible_ to get printf to directly print IO, if you let its final result type be IO () instead of String. (However then the whole function you use it inside must return IO () instead of String.)

Answer (score 3):

It is not about how to correct your code, but to show what is the main (but not only) purpose of `Either a b`.

As a rule it is used as `Right answer` , yes, like right answer and `Left error_message` - like something is not right.

Sure, this meaning of `Either a b` it is only inside the brain, mathematically `Left` is the same as `Right`. But not every time. For example, standard `instance Monad (Either a)` uses `Left` as error.

So, more pleasant code would be `Either Bool Double` in you example.

But ...

If you want to write something like `Left doesn'tMatter` or more simply `Left ()` it is another data for this case - `Maybe a`.

You could rewrite your example to `... -> Maybe Double`:

```
| wrong_pattern -> Nothing
| right_pattern -> Just (mz0 a b c)
```